# Error: Unable to resolve module ./index from /Users/tandamangreen/Desktop/nbaCup/nbaClient/.:

Tags: ios, react-native, startup, npx

```
Error: Unable to resolve module ./index from /Users/tandamangreen/Desktop/nbaCup/nbaClient/.: 

None of these files exist:
  * index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * index/index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/tandamangreen/Desktop/nbaCup/nbaClient/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:136:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/tandamangreen/Desktop/nbaCup/nbaClient/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:231:43)
    at /Users/tandamangreen/Desktop/nbaCup/nbaClient/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:129:24
    at Server._resolveRelativePath (/Users/tandamangreen/Desktop/nbaCup/nbaClient/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1107:12)
    at async Server.requestProcessor [as _processBundleRequest] (/Users/tandamangreen/Desktop/nbaCup/nbaClient/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:450:37)
    at async Server._processRequest (/Users/tandamangreen/Desktop/nbaCup/nbaClient/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:406:9)
```

I had index.js inside the src folder and it should have been in the top level folder. Once I put it there I had no issues.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your startup source file is place in the correct directory, otherwise metro is not going to know where to find it.